# How do I use `:rand` as a unary method with map/collect?

Tags: ruby

I want a vector containing the result of rolling 10 dice (say). I can do this:

```
([6]*10).map{|x|rand(x)}
```

But this gives me a "wrong number of arguments" error:

```
([6]*10).map(:rand)
```

Is there a point-free way to pass the one-argument version of `rand` to `map`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will work:

```
([6]*10).map(&method(:rand))
```

This won't:

```
([6]*10).map(&:rand)
```

`Symbol#to_proc` is (roughly) implemented like this:

```
class Symbol
  def to_proc
    -> *args { args.first.public_send(self, *args.drop(1)) }
  end
end
```

In other words, it takes the first argument as the receiver and the other arguments as arguments to the method that is named by the `Symbol`. So, in your case, it is calling

```
6.rand
```

over and over.

This "kind of" works, because `6` is an `Integer`, `Integer` is an indirect subclass of `Object`, which mixes in `Kernel`, which defines `rand`. But! `rand` is `private`, which means it can only be called without an explicit receiver. Also, you aren't passing any arguments, therefore even if it were `public`, you'd get the behavior of `rand` without arguments, which is a `Float` between 0 and 1.

Whereas `Method#to_proc` passes all arguments to the method (it already has its receiver bound, after all), so in this case, it will call

```
self.rand(6)
```

over and over. Which of course works, because `self` is an `Object`, `Object` includes `Kernel`, and `rand` is defined in `Kernel`.

This won't work as well:

```
([6]*10).map(:rand)
```

For the simple reason that `map` doesn't have any parameters, but you are passing an argument.

Comment: Great, thanks. I shouldn't have jumped to a conclusion in a place where I don't have enough information, as I often say to other people :-( Serves me right. It seems a bit clunky to me, but every language has its own idioms.

Comment: technically in the OP's case it is not calling anything because OP is simply passing a symbol to `map` and `map` does not accept any arguments other than a block. With symbol to proc `&:rand` the error would state "private method `rand` called for 6:Fixnum"

Comment: @engineersmnky: Ah, you're right. My mind filled in the `&` automatically, because what the OP posted doesn't make sense :-D I didn't know `Symbol#to_proc` uses `public_send`, that's good to know (and a good design decision, I might add).

Comment: @engineersmnky: Fair enough. I was deceived by the fact that you can pass a symbol to `reduce`, and I jumped to the conclusion that it would work for `map` as well. Lesson learned.

Comment: @rici: `inject`/`reduce` takes a `Symbol` as an argument, `map`/`collect` doesn't. But even if it did, it would still be equivalent to `6.rand`, at least if we want it to work symmetrically to `inject`/`reduce`. (And if we specified it to work *differently* from `inject`/`reduce`, that would very confusing! It's already confusing enough that one takes a `Symbol` and the other doesn't, imagine what would happen if they both did, but it meant something different.)

Comment: @JörgWMittag: Yeah, I see that. Of course, it would be possible to give integers a `rand` method, and then `map(&:rand)` would work -- as `map(&:abs)` does -- but still not `map(:rand)`. If I understand correctly, `reduce(&:+)` and `reduce(:+)` have the same semantics, because `inject/reduce` accepts a symbol. Would it really create problems if `map` also did so, I wonder? But obviously a comments thread on SO is not the place to conduct this debate, and I'm happy enough to have a solution to my problem, so thanks.

Comment: If rolling dice is really important to this program then making an extension to Integer called `roll` might simplify this considerably. Also: Use [SecureRandom](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/securerandom/rdoc/SecureRandom.html) since `rand` is complete garbage.

Comment: @tadman: according to http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Random.html the default PRNG is a Mersenne twister. Is that not the case? If it is the case, "garbage" seems a bit extreme to me; I don't need a cryptographically secure PRNG, just one which produces a uniform distribution.

Comment: @rici It's truly junk. I've seen cases where it will produce identical sequences due to quirks in the seeding, and where the distributions are just awful. You don't need cryptographically secure, no, but SecureRandom is a really good generator that's *actually* random. Why they don't remove `rand` and just link it to SecureRandom I don't know.

Answer (score 3):

You can write:

```
([6]*10).map(&method(:rand))
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be clean way to write it:

```
10.times.map { rand(6) }
```

Writing it this way makes it easier to see what argument is passed to `rand`.

Comment: Yes, thanks, but I'm aware of that. In the actual application, not all the dice have the same number of sides, so I really need to map `rand` over a vector. I didn't want to get into that issue in the question, though.